# css top attribute behaviour in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I have a problem related with the css 'top' attribute of a Foundation modal.
I have long list of anchors and when I click in each anchor, a modal is opened. I have the css top attibute set to 100px.

When I use Chrome, even if I am in the bottom of the list and I click in one of the last anchors, my modal appears always at 100px of the top of the screen, i.e at 6356px of the top of the body. However, using Firefox, when I click in one of these last anchors, my modal appears at 100px of the top of the body, so I have to scroll up to see the modal. What can I do to make Firefox behave like Chrome?

Comment: are you using  position:absolute ?

Comment: could you mabe provide a fiddle or a code snippet please?